# Linq Map! or Collect!

Tags: ruby, linq, dictionary, collect

What is the Linq equivalent to the [map! or collect!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002213) method in Ruby?

```
   a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
   a.collect! {|x| x + "!" }
   a             #=>  [ "a!", "b!", "c!", "d!" ]
```

I *could* do this by iterating over the collection with a foreach, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant Linq solution.

Comment: Linq takes a functional approach so you usually won't be doing an in-place modification like in your example above. However, this more matches the expected use of map and collect in ruby (without the !)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Map = Select

```
var x = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d"}.Select(s => s+"!");
```

Answer (score 23):

The higher-order function `map` is best represented in [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) which is an extension method in `System.Linq`.

In case you are curious the other higher-order functions break out like this:

`reduce ->` [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx)
`filter ->` [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx)